# Parse Google web history information - log in page redirect

Tags: php, curl, google-api

Since Google doesn't have an API for its web history and I'm trying to retrieve my history data and download it from Google web history the only option I can think of is using `curl` and parsing the content I get from it. The problem is that each time I use my code to get to the google dashboard history from the following url:
https://history.google.com/history/lookup?month=12&day=1&yr=2013&output=rss
Google redirects me to the login page and wants me to login. Is there a way to use OAuth or a method to login to the account and parse the page html code? 
Here is the code I am using to get the page:

```
    <?php
$url = 'https://history.google.com/history/lookup?month=12&day=1&yr=2013&output=rss';

$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.80 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/4.2.14912/870; U; id) Presto/2.4.15"); // set browser/user agent    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'read_header'); // get header
curl_exec($ch);


function read_header($ch, $string) {

   return strlen($string);
}

?>
```

Comment: simply say , 'how 2 hack !' ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only current defense against this attack is for users to remains signed out of Google while using a Wi-Fi hotspot or to set up a personal VPN. Users could also disable Google Web History or purge its contents.

For stuff, check  http://www.pcworld.com/article/239826/google_web_history_vulnerable_to_firesheep_hack.html
download link: https://github.com/downloads/codebutler/firesheep/firesheep-0.1-1.xpi

also check: http://geeklad.com/tools/google-history/google-history.js

Comment: No, I'm not trying to break into anything. I want to download my own Web history data.